# relative url for ulink using dblatex?

Tags: docbook, dblatex

I would like to define a link to an external html file in docbook. The output will be pdf generated using dblatex.
The external html file is in the same set of documents, so I know that in a html file `<a href="../doxyout/class_foo.html#method123">here</a>` would work.
However If I use `<ulink url="../doxyout/class_foo.html#method123">here</ulink>` in docbook,
then when I open the resulting pdf in

- evince: it says that it cannot open `/whatever/directory/the/pdf/file/was/file:../doxyout/class_foo.html#method123`
- acroread: a browser starts at `file:///doxyout/class_foo.html#method123` , which obviously also fails

What should I write in the url attribute to make it work?